# What is a default timeout for ldap connection

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, timeout

I have Ldap connection.Please find below the code snippet :-

```
 public LdapConnection BindLDAPConnection()
    {
        var flag = 0;
        _ldapConnectionUsers = GetLDAPConnection();
        _ldapConnectionUsers.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
        _ldapConnectionUsers.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = false;
        _ldapConnectionUsers.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
        _ldapConnectionUsers.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate =
  ServerCallback;
        //ldap.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate =
        //      (con, cer) => true;
         password = GetPasswordForUser();
         NetworkCredential network = LdapHelper.GetNetworkCredentials();
        _ldapConnectionUsers.Timeout=new TimeSpan(0,0,10,0);
         _ldapConnectionUsers.Bind(network);
         return _ldapConnectionUsers;
    }
```

In the configuration part, I need to set the timeout for this connection.

What is the default timeout for ldap connection?

So that I can give that default timeout in the configuration part?

Comment: Does https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsadsi/2012/06/06/how-to-specify-timeout-for-ldap-bind-in-net/ help?

Comment: Show us the part of code where you connect to Ldap.

Comment: I have edited the code with my connection code. (As comment part doesn't allow that much space). :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`LdapConnection.Timeout`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.ldapconnection.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx) overrides [**`DirectoryConnection.Timeout`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.directoryconnection.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx) that defaults to **30 seconds**.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer of 30 seconds is not presize.
The library that manages the TCP sessions for the LDAP Server and the Kerberos Key Distribution Center (KDC) uses a scavenging thread to monitor for sessions that are inactive, and disconnects these sessions if they're idle too long. The scavenging thread runs every 30 seconds to clean out these sessions.

The KDC registry entry **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Kdc\NewConnectionTimeout** controls the idle time, using a default of 10 seconds. However, based on the implementation of the scavenging, the effective interval is **0-30 seconds**. Therefore newly created sessions may be disconnected immediately by the server sporadically.

When you set NewConnectionTimeout to 40 or higher, you receive a time-out window of 30-90 seconds. When you use 70 or higher, you receive 60-120 seconds for the time-out. For more information about the NewConnectionTimeout registry value, see [Kerberos protocol registry entries and KDC configuration keys in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/kerberos-protocol-registry-kdc-configuration-keys).